# Telling dotnet which private key to use to decrypt incoming XML documents?

Tags: .net, xml, encryption, cross-platform, saml

This is a question about XML crypto key management in the dot net environment and cross platform.

I'm working with SAML 2.0, in which one machine -- an identity provider -- sends another machine -- a service provider -- an XML message known as an Assertion. The Assertion instructs the service provider to grant access to a user named in it.

All assertions are signed with a private key held by the identity provider. SOME assertions are also encrypted with a public key held by the identity provider, to be decrypted with a private key at the receiving service provider.

The trouble is, some of these encrypted assertion documents don't carry any identification of the keypair used to encrypt them.  The Microsoft Dot Net [EncryptedXML class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh5h3ft3(v=vs.100).aspx) has no way (that I can see) to tell it "use a particular key pair to decrypt this document".

The way SAML works, the service provider identifies the private key by knowing which identity provider sent the message.

There is no problem with non-cross-platform documents. Documents ENcrypted with that dotnet EncryptedXML class itself end up with the X509 certificate - in effect the public half of the keypair -- embedded in plain text in them along with the cipher text for the session key. The decryption method uses that certificate to identify the private key so it can decrypt the session key and then the message.

The problem is with documents encrypted on other platforms. They don't carry the X509 certificate. The EncryptedXML class can't figure out which private key to use, and so just chucks an exception.

The Microsoft encryption inserts the following stanzas into the document.

```
       EncryptedKey                (present in many documents)
         EncryptionMethod          (present in many documents)
           KeyInfo                 (absent in non-ms documents)
             X509Data                
               X509Certificate
```

Now I have a solution to this problem, which inserts the last three of those items into the document, using the correct certificate.  This is it.

```cs
XmlNode encryptedKey = doc.LookForNode(@"EncryptedKey");
if (null == encryptedKey) 
    throw new CryptographicException("No key information in encrypted document");

XmlNode encryptionMethod = encryptedKey.LookForNode(@"EncryptionMethod");
if (null == encryptionMethod) 
    throw new CryptographicException("No key encryption method in encrypted document");

XmlNode keyinfo = encryptedKey.LookForNode(@"KeyInfo");
if (null == keyinfo) {
  /* no key info, cons up the required stanza of XML based on our public key */
  const string keynamespace = @"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
  XmlNode ki = doc.CreateElement(null, @"KeyInfo", keynamespace);
  XmlNode xd = doc.CreateElement(null, @"X509Data", keynamespace);
  XmlNode xc = doc.CreateElement(null, @"X509Certificate", keynamespace);  /* has public key cert in it */
  xc.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(key.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));

  xd.AppendChild(xc);
  ki.AppendChild(xd);
  encryptedKey.InsertAfter(ki, encryptionMethod);
}

EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(doc);
exml.DecryptDocument();
```

This works. `DecryptDocument` succeeds when the document is thus augmented. But it seems like a big kludge. Is there a better way to do this in dot net? Is there some sort of best practice for key management in this world of cross-platform document exchange?

Comment: Doesn't the EncryptedXml.DecryptKey Method (Byte[], RSA, Boolean) method have an RSA parameter? Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5daxt12d(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Just a note - to include or not include the certificate is defined not by the platform, but is a voluntary decision of the encryption code (and its author of course).

Comment: Understood. By "platform" I mean the SAML identity provider platform, not something like J2EE or dotnet 4.5 or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what to do in C# to solve this problem. This solution adds the missing elements to the XML document, then decrypts it.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// decrypt a document with the specified key
/// </summary>
/// <param name="docin">encrypted document</param>
/// <param name="key">the key pair</param>
/// <returns>the decrypted document</returns>
public static XmlDocument DecryptDocument(
    this XmlDocument docin, X509Certificate2 key,
    StringBuilder log = null)
{
    /* first step: make sure encrypted xml contains all these items.
     * EncryptedKey                (present in many documents)
     *   EncryptionMethod          (present in many documents)
     *     KeyInfo                 (absent in some documents)
     *       X509Data                 ditto
     *         X509Certificate        ditto with x.509 cert in Base4
     *  
     * because that's the way dotnet EncryptedXML figures out
     * under the covers which key to use to decode the document,
     * bless its pointed little head.  */

    var encryptedKey = docin.LookForNode(@"EncryptedKey");
    if (null == encryptedKey)
    {
        /* not an encrypted document, give it right back. */
        return docin;
    }
    /* leave the input document unchanged, manipulate a copy */
    var doc = (XmlDocument) docin.Clone();

    encryptedKey = doc.LookForNode(@"EncryptedKey");
    if (null == encryptedKey)
    {
        if (null != log) 
             log.Append("No encryption key in document").AppendLine();
        return docin;
    }

    var encryptionMethod = encryptedKey.LookForNode(@"EncryptionMethod");
    if (null == encryptionMethod)
    {
        if (null != log) 
            log.Append("No key encryption method in document").AppendLine();
        return docin;
    }

    /*create required stanza of XML based on our public key */
    const string keynamespace = SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl;
    XmlNode ki = doc.CreateElement(null, @"KeyInfo", keynamespace);
    XmlNode xd = doc.CreateElement(null, @"X509Data", keynamespace);
    XmlNode xc = doc.CreateElement(null, @"X509Certificate", keynamespace);
    xc.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(key.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));

    /* insert it into the received document */
    xd.AppendChild(xc);
    ki.AppendChild(xd);
    encryptedKey.InsertAfter(ki, encryptionMethod);
    if (null != log) log.Append("Adding KeyInfo data to encrypted document").AppendLine();

    /* handle the decrypt */
    try
    {
        var exml = new EncryptedXml(doc);
        exml.DecryptDocument();
    }
    catch (CryptographicException cre)
    {
        if (null != log) log.Append(cre.Message).AppendLine();
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GetDecryptionKey is a virtual method in the EncryptedXml class...  When you don't want to use the default Microsoft logic for determining the key, you can create your own override of that method.  Although you then have to implement the logic to decrypt the generated symmetric key using your private key.

Referring back to the reference source provided by Microsoft for EncryptedXml, I've used code like this:

```cs
class EncryptedXmlWithPreconfiguredAsymmetricKey : EncryptedXml
{
    public readonly X509Certificate2 _encryptionCert;
    public EncryptedXmlWithPreconfiguredAssymetricKey(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 encryptionCert) : base(xmlDoc)
    {
        _encryptionCert = encryptionCert;
    }

    public override System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, string symmetricAlgorithmUri)
    {
        if (encryptedData == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedData");

        if (encryptedData.KeyInfo == null)
            return null;
        IEnumerator keyInfoEnum = encryptedData.KeyInfo.GetEnumerator();
        KeyInfoRetrievalMethod kiRetrievalMethod;
        KeyInfoName kiName;
        KeyInfoEncryptedKey kiEncKey;
        EncryptedKey ek = null;

        while (keyInfoEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            kiName = keyInfoEnum.Current as KeyInfoName;

            kiRetrievalMethod = keyInfoEnum.Current as KeyInfoRetrievalMethod;

            kiEncKey = keyInfoEnum.Current as KeyInfoEncryptedKey;
            if (kiEncKey != null)
            {
                ek = kiEncKey.EncryptedKey;
                break;
            }
        }

        // if we have an EncryptedKey, decrypt to get the symmetric key
        if (ek != null)
        {
            // now process the EncryptedKey, loop recursively
            // If the Uri is not provided by the application, try to get it from the EncryptionMethod 
            if (symmetricAlgorithmUri == null)
            {
                if (encryptedData.EncryptionMethod == null)
                    throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_MissingAlgorithm");
                symmetricAlgorithmUri = encryptedData.EncryptionMethod.KeyAlgorithm;
            }
            byte[] key = ek.CipherData.CipherValue;
            if (key == null)
                throw new CryptographicException("Cryptography_Xml_MissingDecryptionKey");

            // Ignore any information about the asymmetric key in the XML, and just use our predefined certificate
            var rsaKey = (RSA)_encryptionCert.PrivateKey;

            byte[] symkey = EncryptedXml.DecryptKey(key, rsaKey, true);

            SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg = (SymmetricAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(symmetricAlgorithmUri);
            symAlg.Key = symkey;
            return symAlg;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the private key from the certificate (provided the cert has the private key) like this:

```
rsaProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```

Then on your EncryptedXML, add a key mapping:

```
encryptedXML.AddKeyNameMapping("rsaKey", rsaProvider );
```

Comment: This works great when the document contains a `KeyInfo` stanza naming this "rsaKey" item. But I don't have any control over the incoming documents, and they don't contain such stanzas.

Comment: Take a look at the following: https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/FubuMVC.Saml2/blob/master/src/FubuSaml2/Encryption/AssertionXmlEncryptor.cs. Here they do it by extracting the  key element out of the assertion

Comment: @JasonGordon Is rsaKey the KeyInfo tag name.  I'm a bit confused there.My KeyInfo looks like this <KeyInfo 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                            <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">j0ZKF......=</o:KeyIdentifier>
</o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo>

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this lybrary.
https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2

You use something like this and your xml is decrypted.

```
using (RSA rsa = privateKeyCert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    new Saml2EncryptedXml(xmlDoc, rsa).DecryptDocument();
}
```